# CERN ROOT resource recommendation

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, data-analysis

During my BSc., I used Python, C and Scilab in addition to Excel to perform data analysis on lab experiments. However, unfortunately I never got the chance to use ROOT which is one of the most widely used program designed to analyze data in particle physics and astrophysics. I searched online and got a few good tutorials including [CERN ROOT](https://root.cern/doc/master/group__Tutorials.html). I'd appreciate good tutorials/materials/videos on this context.

Comment: Do you need it for professional reasons or just out of curiosity?

Comment: For professional reasons

Comment: All right, just asking, because there are alternatives to C++, which have a much easier learning curve, such as : Crystal (Ruby-like), Nim (Python-like), and Rust (who has a style of its own) or even Golang (Go) which is very powerful at handling concurrency in a very readable way.

Comment: … last but not least, Root appears to have python bindings: https://root.cern/manual/python/

Answer (score 1):

You can check [these slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/189f0qsDEnMSk2R5KWLRPz2TdEV5kTfXH1VcuAra4cnU/edit?usp=sharing). They are used in a 2 day basic course at CERN. See [this repository](https://github.com/root-project/training) for other official courses. They also gave many exercises for each course. They contain problems based on c++(.C macros), python (jupyter notebooks and .py) etc. Also [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPz-dNjdx40&list=PLLybgCU6QCGWLdDO4ZDaB0kLrO3maeYAe) may be useful. All these are for beginners.

Comment: Already seen the playlist but I will definitely check the two other links in detail.

Comment: Please see the [resource recommendation guidelines](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698), and consider [edit]ing this answer to follow them. In its current form (v2) this answer is just a list of links.